# Rails Devise - changing minimum password length on production app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys just wondering what would happen if I changed the minimum password length on my app. For development i had it set to 3 characters and want to change it back to 8 however, my app already has 100+ users. If I do change it, will the current users still be able to log in or will they be unable to access their accounts?

Comment: This kind of stuffs is better to check it yourself

Comment: The way to go with things like these is to replicate the issue locally. If you can, try to take a production database dump and modify the config.

Comment: They will be able to sign in and sign up smoothly, it won't affect the existing records. But while changing old password or signing up for new account, users will have to follow the new setting.

You can check such settings in development environment and the result will be same in production.

Answer (score 8):

It will not create a problem for old records. You can change password length in devise.rb

> config.password_length = 8..128

Better to work in local environment than it will be good to go for prod.

Comment: while changing password? any effects

Comment: While changing password no problem, But new password will be a length of 8